# Error formulacion de sintaxis Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
        return view('test',[
            'title'=> $request->query(key:'title',deault:'Valor default')
        ]);
    }
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Creo que el problema es que esta formulada en una version anterior y la sintaxis no es la misma, alguien me puede ayudar a transformarlo a la version 6?

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 class DashboardController extends Controller
{

   public function index(Request $request) {
        return view('test')->with([
            'title' => $request->query('title', 'Valor default')
        ]);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes sustituir tu función de la siguiente forma sin agregar el tipo de dato para la función

```
public function index() {
    $request = request();
    return view('test')->with([
        'title' => $request->query('title', 'Valor default')
    ]);
}
```

El motivo por el segundo error es que en el parent controller tienes la misma funcion index sin parámetros. Sustituye por el código que edité.

Comment: y eso es por el cambio de versión?

Comment: ¿Que versión tenías?

Comment: la ultima version, ahora me arroja este err > ErrorException
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::index(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index()

Comment: Se necesitaria mas código de la cabecera de tu controlador para ver el error

Comment: acabo de añadirlo al post inicial

Comment: funciona colega